# Spring Boot - RabbitMQ - Changing message content type from octet-stream to json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, rabbitmq

I having issue getting from my Byte[] message received in RabbitMQ converted into some object based on a model.

I'm using Spring Boot.

In the application I have implemented `RabbitListenerConfigurer`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application : RabbitListenerConfigurer {
...

override fun configureRabbitListeners(registrar: RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar) {
        registrar.messageHandlerMethodFactory = messageHandlerMethodFactory()
    }

    @Bean
    fun messageHandlerMethodFactory(): MessageHandlerMethodFactory {
        val messageHandlerMethodFactory = DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory()
        messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter())
        return messageHandlerMethodFactory
    }

    @Bean
    fun consumerJackson2MessageConverter(): MappingJackson2MessageConverter {
        return MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
    }

}
```

I then have a listener (the `println` is just for the time being for me to check) like:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = ["success.queue"])
    fun receivedSuccessMessage(data: MyModel) {
        println(data)
    }
```

And the model itself looks like (again simplified just for testing):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class MyModel(
        val input: Any,
        val metadata: Any
)
```

Now whenever that queue gets a message the error i get is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.models.MyModel] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[1429]
```

Also to add the message I'm receving into that success queue looks like this:

`{"input":"somestuff", "metadata": "somestuff"}`

And I also just noticed that the message type is coming in as `content_type:    application/octet-stream`. This is out of my control as thats just what I am receiving from the service that puts the message in there:

[image]

Any ideas why this is - I assumed that `RabbitListenerConfigurer` implementation I have does the conversion for all messages from byte array into whatever model I specify.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Ok I got this working, however I'm quite confused about something:

This is what I added in:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var connectionFactory : ConnectionFactory

@Bean
    fun rabbitListenerContainerFactory(): SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory {
        val factory = SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory()
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
        factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(SomeBusiness())

        return factory
    }
```

And then the actual conversion like this:

```
class SomeBusiness : MessagePostProcessor {
    @Throws(AmqpException::class)
    override fun postProcessMessage(message: Message): Message {
        println("WE WENT IN NOW")
        println()
        if (message.messageProperties.contentType == "application/octet-stream") {
            message.messageProperties.contentType = "application/json"
        }
        return message
    }
}
```

However the thing I don't understand is I already have my `messageHandlerMethodFactory` function which I assumed did all the work around listening to messages. Now that I have `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` is there any concern of anything conflicting. Or is it perfectly valid, namely I need `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` as it implements `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` which gives me access to the method `setAfterReceivePostProcessors`.

Again, any explanation would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are receiving `content_type: application/octet-stream` and this can't changed.
You could use Spring Interceptor Or Servlet Filter to convert the content type `application/octet-stream` to `application/json`.

[Example using HandlerInterceptor for Spring Boot](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor) Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: The thing is the app I'm writing listens to several queues, and one of them actually sends `application/json` - so how can I say convert only specific queues?
Also, could you point me to the interface/docs that does this conversion?

Comment: In the Interceptor check of contentype if it is `octet-stream` then convert to `json` otherwise just leave it as it is.

Comment: Sorry, this intereceptor - this is something I need to implement? (New to Spring so still a little overwhelmed by it all)

Comment: I took a look that example and thats for rest APIs right?
I came across this https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#post-processing and the use of `setAfterReceivePostProcessors()`
However I;m seriously confused on hows it used - you know any good examples of usage?

Comment: Thanks - so I got it working from thinking about your answer - however I don't understand why it all works lol - I've left the details in the UPDATE section of my question, if you have any ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below source which is working for me,

```
public void convertByteArrayToObject(Message<?> message) {

    Object request = message.getPayload();
    Object result = null;
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = (byte[]) request;
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

        result = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream).readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solution below helped me to solve it.

**Solution:**

Spring understand only "contentType", not "content_type". So, just set "contentType" property for your message, for example (in my case message producer was not spring app):

```
String json = ...;
TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(json);
textMessage.setStringProperty("contentType", "application/json");
```

**Explanation:**

Class `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` has method `canConvertFrom(Message<?> message, @Nullable Class<?> targetClass)`. That method checks if headers contains supported mime types. And if to dive deeper, we will find that `AbstractMessageConverter.getMimeType(MessageHeaders header)` has `contentTypeResolver`, who gets appropriate property. Instance of that object located in CompositeMessageConverterFactory, it's `DefaultContentResolver,` which gets content type in method  `resolve(MessageHeaders headers)`:

```
Object contentType = headers.get(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Where `public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "contentType";`